# Unable to run the commands of reindexing in magento

Tags: magento, magento2

I have purchased the VPS server and install the required extension of php in my apache, and now when i install the magento there was one extension missing i.e `pdo_mysql` and when i tried again to install the setup it confirms that all extension are okay, but there wasn't `pdo_mysql` extesion enabled from my side. and the setup completed. after completion when I run the commands to reindex the data it give me the error that

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Status: 404 Not Found
```

I have also tried to install the extension `pdo_mysql` by going to WHM->software-> Modeule installer->PHP Extensions and Applications Package->Show Available Modules->Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_PDO (0.2.0)-> and when tried ti install this it gives me this error.

```
Failed to download pear/Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_PDO within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.2.0, stability "beta", use "channel://pear.php.net/Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_PDO-0.2.0" to install
install failed
```

I am also attaching the scrrenshot of SSH, I have tried all the commands and its not working.

NOTE: I have purchased the VPS server from godaddy and installed the setup of magento 2.3.0 and Still I am unable to find the extension under the Easy Apache 4 -> customize->php extensions] so please guide me what i have to do for this and one thing more there isn't any extensions to be showned in the php.ini file which i can say that there is duplication of the extesions. I have also checked that by going to WHM->software=>Multi PHP ini editor.[image: SSH Screensho]

Answer (score 0):

Check your `php.ini` or any `pdo.ini` file`(etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini)` , may be `extension = "pdo.so"` is loading `twice`. Remove one of them, restart apache and then check.